# precision attribute getting added automatically in edmx file

Tags: .net, entity-framework, edmx

When I update my edmx file using "Update model from database..." operation, datetime fields automatically get precision attribute added to them. This doesn't happens when other users do the same(we both connect to same database). Could someone suggest where I should look to avoid this scenario. Also if this is something trivial and I need not worry about it.

[image]

I am using .NET Framwork 4 and SQL Server 2012.

Thanks

Comment: Do all the users have the same environment? Are you sure that both of you are connected to the same database?

Comment: I am sure that we both connect to same DB, for environment I am not sure about everything but we both have same OS running on different laptops. This must be some environment issue but that is my problem that I don't know what to compare apart from OS and SQL Server version.